# Converting text into ASCII/ISO-8859-1

Tags: command-line, character-encoding, conversion

I'm looking for some tool that can convert text, ideally from UTF-8 (but ISO-8859-2 and WINDOWS-1250 would be fine) into ASCII/ISO-8859-1?

I have seen some online transliteration tools but I need something for the command line (and iconv is refusing to convert the file).

Comment: Hm, `iconv` is *the* command line tool for that task.  Mind to share how exactly it refuses to serve you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, iconv refuses to convert the file if it contains characters that do not exist in the target character set. Use `//TRANSLIT` to “downgrade” such characters.

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t iso8859-1//TRANSLIT
```

Comment: Oh, that's totally awesome, thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok to use Python, give a try to [slugify](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/slugify) which is made to do character conversion such as `é => e`. And forget my previous answer mentioning `konwert`, which is used to format conversion.

Comment: Hmm, the description says otherwise. Are you sure?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: ok, maybe I read too quickly your question... If what you need is a not only a **format** conversion but a character conversion (i.e. é => e), give a try to [slugify](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/slugify) then.